# Is there map $\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which maps great circles to lines?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spherical-geometry, geodesic

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{S}^2$ be some small open set.
Is there a smooth map $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which preserves the geodesics?

(i.e if $\alpha$ is (part of) a great circle, then I require $f \circ \alpha$ to be a straight line).

(There is no such conformal map, since [every conformal geodesics-preserving map is a scaled isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136773/a-conformal-geodesic-map-must-be-a-scaled-isometry). In particular the stereographic projection is excluded from the search).

Comment: How do you name points on $\Bbb S^2$?

Comment: There is the [gnomic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection)

Comment: @kimchilover but $U$ isn't the whole hemisphere

Comment: @KennyLau The OP asks for a map on a small neighborhood of a given point.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks! That seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: Now this question remains unanswered, and nobody apart from the OP (original poster) has learnt anything.

Comment: Note that it is actually the *gnomonic* projection. A gnomon is not a gnome, it is a part of a sundial.

Comment: @Rahul Whoops, and thanks!  Gnomonic, I'll try to remember it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434466/is-there-map-mathbbs2-to-mathbbr2-which-maps-great-circles-to-lines#comment5028710_2434466) by kimchi lover,

the [gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection#Properties)  maps great circles to straight lines. (It can be defined on a subset of the hemisphere).